# The end of the "consume scientists" side mission chain - did I get it right?

Tags: prototype

While playing Prototype yesterday, I completed the last "consume scientists" side-mission, which revealed **Karen Parker**'s location on the map for me to go and exact my revenge.

After entering the building where she was hiding and being treated to a cutscene which hints that Alex kills her, I was expecting something more (I was almost certain I'd get a Web of Intrigue clip). However, nothing unusual happened after the cutscene and I simply appeared outside the building I previously entered.

Is this what was supposed to happen? Does the fact that I killed her come to play later in the game (a simple yes no will do for this one, as if it does come into play I wouldn't want to know how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supposed to happen.

Comment: How half-baked of them, then. Seeing how I finished the game since asking this question, I also know it doesn't seem to come into play in any way.